# Delete query records in workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

Everytime, when I open mysql-workbench,it takes a long time to load my query records like this. [image]
I want to delete them completely.But I can't find the way. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close them. Right-click on one of the tabs and choose "**Close Other Tabs**" from the context-menu. The reason they show up is because you have the "**Save snapshot of open editors on close**" preference enabled. You might want to disable that, or use it with care. For additional information about this setting, see [the related documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-preferences-sql-editor.html).